# Access SPI by PeripheralManagerService on Hikey

Tags: android, gpio, spi, android-things, peripherals

I am trying to send data to a device which is connected to SPI of hikey960 platform. Hikey is running on normal mobile Android. Is it possible to run androidthings api on development platform like Hikey ?

```
PeripheralManagerService manager = new PeripheralManagerService();
List<String> deviceList = manager.getSpiBusList();
if (deviceList.isEmpty()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "No SPI bus available on this device.");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "List of available devices: " + deviceList);
}
```

I build an apk with above code. and while installing missing library error is coming. obviously it is due missing android library in normal android sdk. Is ther any workaround or way to write data to spi devices on android platform.

Error-

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.androidthings.myproject-1: Package com.example.androidthings.myproject requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.things; failing!.

Answer (score 0):

For now Android things only runs on the selected dev kits (nxp and raspberry pi) maybe once it's released -it's still on developer preview- they'll open it to more devices.